# Does GLFW work on IOS application?

Tags: android, ios, opengl-es, ios-simulator, simulation

I am trying to write an application for a simulation software that relies on openGL and GLWF for the graphic part of it, and I'm not sure if it would work on IOS. Also if it the answer is no, is there anything else that could be used instead of GLWF? I know that there are some frameworks within IOS, but since I need to have this spp running on Android too in the future, I'm looking for something independent of IOS, so I don't have to go through all this again with Android.

Thanks, :)

Comment: Have you considered SDL2? GLFW is not officially supported on Android, and I'm not sure about IOS. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

No.
In official repo (https://github.com/glfw/glfw/) written - GLFW supports Windows XP and later, OS X 10.7 Lion and later, and Linux and other Unix-like systems with the X Window System.